# Email Notifications don't work!

Tags: bug, notifications, email

Even though I have correctly setup and verified my email address and activated Daily Inbox notifications, I never receive an E-Mail.

(No, there is no message in my SPAM box either)

[image: Email Settings]

Comment: If you read them on the site (clicking the "Recent inbox messages" icon in top bar) you won't get email.

Comment: May be you can provide any screenshot so that you question is understood properly.

Comment: No, so far I never received any mail notifications. So lets try again. Please answer to this comment and I will wait for 3 hours (changed it in the settings now).

Comment: @Tigerix All right, fire away.

Comment: @Tigerix too bad you didn't ping anyone, this way nobody got notified of your comment.

Comment: Yay, it's the first time ever that I receive email notification. So it seems to work now!